# Getting Fatal error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm, adobe-brackets

I want to create `window installer` but facing some problem from last 4 days
on exectuion of `common.js` facing this error.

What i analyzed:

```
child = child_process.spawn(cmd, args, opts);
children.push(child);
```

..is not executing properly. Can someone help me?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about running `grunt installer` on the [brackets-shell](https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell) source code? Make sure you've followed the extra setup steps here:

- https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/blob/master/installer/win/README.MD
- https://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell/blob/master/installer/mac/README.MD

(depending on your platform)

If you're building something other than Brackets itself, ***please*** be sure to change the Info.plist bundle id (Mac) and installer GUIDs (Win) so that whatever app you're building doesn't become entangled with Brackets installs on the same machine.